# Is it ok to leave my messages registered in mvvm light?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a pretty simple WPF application using MVVM Light framework.  One main window with a listbox and 2 buttons.  Clicking one of the buttons will overlay a usercontrol over my main window (like an adorner type).  This user control has its own view model and it is registered for one message that tells the view model which item in my main window's listbox is selected.  Clicking the exit button on my usercontrol sends a message to the main view model telling it to hide the usercontrol.  Pretty much the same setup for my second usercontrol.

So as I am still learning WPF/MVVM I'm not 100% on what I should do about unregistering the messages (or even using the cleanup/dispose methods to clean my viewmodels, but I'll save that for another question to stay on topic).  I believe I am following what would be called a "singleton" approach where 3 viewmodels are constructed on application startup and will stay around for the life of my application and there will always only be one of each type of viewmodel.

So the question is, do I have to unregister my messages given the application structure?  If I do have to unregister, when? (my guess would be sometime when I click that exit button or right after I receive the message since I'm not going to be receiving any messages until after I'm done using that view)  And if I do have to unregister, when and how can I reregister the message, especially since I am not creating a new viewmodel everytime and I need my viewmodel to receive the message right when I start using it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're talking about when you refer to "registering messages" but I will say one thing: view models should never be singletons! View models in MVVM are the logical representation of the view in its current state, if their corresponding views no longer exist then they shouldn't either. You can probably get away with it for your main view model i.e. the one behind the top-level window which is always open, but even then I wouldn't advise using an actual singleton. Much better to keep it a regular class and use dependency injection to give it singleton scoping.

Comment: Eek you're not making my life easy Mark!  DI is still one of the topics I am not so knowledgeable about, though I know a little of the basics.  TBH this is my first wpf application and I went with the MVVM Light framework hoping it would help me out a little bit, biggest help so far has been the built in messenger.  That said, it comes with a ViewModelLocator which I don't really know how to use so well.  If you're telling me I should be creating a new viewmodel right before (during/after?) I use it then delete it right when I'm done with it, I need to go do more homework.

Comment: Ah ok, don't worry about DI then, that'll come later. Regarding your view models, imagine you have to write a fully-functional, working app in C# but another team will come in later and do the actual graphics widgets and hardware interfacing. Your app needs to create logical objects containing the data for all the UI elements and it has to respond to button presses and key strokes etc but the other team will fill in the final details. That's pretty much what MVVM is, it just so happens that the "other team" is the view consisting of all the parts you write yourself in XAML.

Comment: I've been trying to read some more articles and poke around at my application to get a better understanding of what's going on.  Right now my ViewModelLocator registers my 3 ViewModels; the main view and the 2 other views that will pop up.  When I launch my application, all 3 of my view models construct during startup.  Is this correct?  The way you're making it sound is that my main view model should construct when I start the application, then my other 2 views should only construct right when I call to show the view.

Comment: That's correct, you shouldn't be creating all your view models at startup unless the views are going to be visible immediately.  A "view model" is exactly that: the model of the currently visible view. As a general rule of thumb there's a 1:1 relationship between views that are currently visible and their corresponding view models, and any data that needs to persist between views usually belongs in other layers like the model or DAL.